# Output UIView as video stream

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es

Is it possible to stream content/context of a UIView as a direct video stream in Swift? I am not really looking for a “view screenshotting” functionality and than assembling video, this solution is possible but the framerate is far from ideal.
Update: maybe using OpenGL view?

Comment: Do you mean you want something like screen share functionality of skype desktop app?

Comment: I need to mirror content of a specific view on an embedded external device. At the moment I only use screenshots but that is not a good solution at all. :(

Comment: Would anyone have an idea if OpenGL could be an option? I don't mind not using UIKit ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. View screenshots:** What's your current solution of timing function ?

I believe if you use CADisplayLink, you can get better frame rate. As in my project, I can get ~15-20fps live streaming on full screen video view on iPhone 7Plus.

**2. Using ReplayKit:** I think I don't need to rewrite the introduction in another way because the Apple's docs were so clear.

> Record or stream video from the screen, and audio from the app and
>   microphone.
>
> Using the ReplayKit framework, users can record video from the screen,
>   and audio from the app and microphone. They can then share their
>   recordings with other users through email, messages, and social media.
>   You can build app extensions for live broadcasting your content to
>   sharing services. ReplayKit is incompatible with AVPlayer content.

The frame rate is quite higher than draw screenshot of views but currently it only supports capturing the whole screen.

So if you want to achieve capturing just a view, may be think about this way: Crop the buffer array of the output CMSampleBufferRef frame.

edit: If it's about mirroring a view to an external screen then we could have other solutions than ReplayKit or view screenshots.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Tony! Would you by any chance have an idea if OpenGL could be an option? I don't mind not using UIKit

Comment: Do you mean using GLView to render things on that ? Then the question is quite different than the original one.

If you want to mirror a view to an external screen, why not just mimic that view hierarchy on another window ?

Can you explain your case ? If it's about mirroring a view to an external screen then we could have other solutions than ReplayKit or view screenshots.